# Customizing Web Authentication Broker appearence, programmatically

Tags: c#, facebook, microsoft-metro

I was fiddling around with integrating facebook into a Metro style application and I connect to facebook through a WebAuthenticationBroker like this:

```
 WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                    WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                    loginUrl,
                                                    endUri);
            if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                var callbackUri = new Uri(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString());
                var facebookOAuthResult = _fb.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(callbackUri);
                var accessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                {
                    // User is not logged in, they may have canceled the login
                }
                else
                {
                    App.AccessToken = accessToken;

                    // User is logged in and token was returned
                    LoginSucceded();
                }

            }
```

My real problem is that this is ugly as hell, is it possible to somehow customize the `WebAuthenticationBroker` , even if its created programatically? I've found notes how to do it, but in those examples they somehow use CSS on a HTML, which I obviously don't have.

Q: Is it possible to somehow change the style of the parts which are not blurred out?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, the hack with html and css is done using the cascading property and in fact is an hack that could not work in the future.
Facebook always render its own auth window, in every device.

Comment: @Mangiucugna Yeah, but what about the "Connecting to a service" text, it is in fact not rendered by facebook, but the Authentication Broker, is it not?

Comment: Check out [Windows 8/RT WebAuthenticationBroker view issue - Alternative](http://www.naweed.info/Links/Post/9)

Answer (score 0):

The provider has the ability to customize the UI with metadata tags on their page, but like Mangiucugna said; the technique you referred to is a hack which may not be supported later. This link explains what UI elements the provider has access to customize:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856908.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I, myself, have found this link too, but I could not figure out where to put those meta-tags exactly, could you help me with that?

Comment: Unfortunately, your application doesn't have anywhere you can edit the broker's UI. You can only access the provider through the APIs in code, and the broker generates a modal dialog where the provider's authentication window will get displayed. Of course, if you are authenticating to a site that you developed yourself, then you obviously have access to the source html for the page and can customize the look. With regard to your example, you are authenticating through facebook there so you won't have access to customize the UI. So in this case the answer to your question is no you can't do it.

Comment: Then how is the link relevat? I mean, why would Microsoft say that you can customize this and that, when you cant?

Comment: Ah ok. I understand what you want to do, but I think you're just not seeing that there are two sides to the web authentication broker. One side is your web application. The other is the provider's web app which contains the credentials. The page you want to customize is on the provider's end and they can use the meta tags to customize it. In that example it's up to facebook to customize the look of the Windows 8 style IE title banners etc.

Comment: No, It's okay, I get it now. Does the Connecting title ('Connecting to a service') belong to Facebook too? I mean, it would seem reasonable to assume that the title is created by the broker, because of the styling and the back arrow and such, that one could assume that one could customize, because it really is the one thing that I can't get over. It disturbs the style of the app and according to your prev comment, its style can only be integrated if I change my app according to the Broker and not customize the broker's style to go well with my design. So could I just change the title?

Comment: Or is that up to facebook too?

Comment: Yeah, it's only on the provider side so facebook would have the control on there. I agree that it's kind of crappy. It might even only be applicable to IE, but I wouldn't know because I haven't tested it in other browsers.